# Nx 16, can't configure a proxy in storybook vite and react library

Tags: vite, storybook, nrwl-nx

i'm using nx 16, i'am trying to configure storybook in a react library all configured with vite, i have tried putting the proxy configuration in many locations. In an application the proxy works fine, the problem is only in libs.

I've tried the next files and locations:

libs/mylib/.storybook/main.js

```
    const config = {
      stories: ['../src/lib/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
      addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
      framework: {
        name: '@storybook/react-vite',
        options: {
          builder: {
            viteConfigPath: 'libs/actividad/ui/vite.config.ts',
            server: {
              proxy: {
                '/intervi': {
                  target: 'http://localhost:9000',
                  changeOrigin: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

In libs/mylib/vite.config.ts

```
...
      server: {
        proxy: {
          '/intervi': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9000',
            changeOrigin: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

In libs/mylib/project.json

```
        "storybook": {
          "executor": "@nx/storybook:storybook",
          "options": {
            "port": 4400,
            "proxyConfig": "apps/proxy.conf.json",
            "configDir": "libs/actividad/ui/.storybook"
          },
        },
    ..
```

With no results, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

I guess, i made some typing mistake, the code should be in viteFinal method in .storybook/main.js, like the docs say:

```
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite';
const config = {
  stories: ['../src/lib/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-vite',
    options: {
      builder: {
        viteConfigPath: 'libs/actividad/ui/vite.config.ts',
      },
    },
  },
  async viteFinal(config) {
    // Merge custom configuration into the default config
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      // Add dependencies to pre-optimization
      optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['storybook-dark-mode'],
      },
      server: {
        proxy: {
          '/intervi': {
            target: 'http://localhost:9000',
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: I've created a demo project in: https://github.com/hanspoo/react-vite-storybook